# Is this possible to create a list of groups and see only its posts on Facebook wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, list

I am trying to figure out how to see a series of posts on a huge list of Facebook groups. I wish I could see them separately in a kind of friends' list style. Is there a way to do it on Facebook or even using another app?

---

Edit: To give some context, I believe this very idea is already implemented when it comes to friends. The reference can be found on this post from Facebook Help: [How can I use lists to organize my friends?](https://www.facebook.com/help/200538509990389) .

Answer (score 1):

You cant create a specific list of groups, but you can see posts from your whole list of groups at the following URL https://facebook.com/?sk=groups

The Groups feed can be pretty limited in the number of posts it displays, but i think its the closest thing to what you want that you can get with Facebook's native functionality.